# twitter bootstrap class visible-* dont work on mobiles and tablets

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to use `visible-xs`,`visible-sm`,`visible-md` on a div like this: 
 
 `<div class="badge" class="visible-xs visible-sm">text</div>`

But this not seems to work on mobile phone or tablet,
 on desktop however this works when i manipulate with window, 
 on mobiles it works when i switch browser to "show as desktop". 
 
Strange is that, everything else works, even the classes `hidden-*`

Does anyone have any suggestion, how to solve this?

Comment: An actual Demo would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`visible-*` should work fine with mobile devices.

show us an example please.

Answer (score 0):

According to Twitter Bootstrap's website: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

If you are using the current version of Bootstrap: 3.2.0, this is now no longer kosher. It *should* still be able to work, but you may want to try `.visible-sm-*`. The  `*`  is often a place holder for block, inline, or inline-block. Ex: `.visible-sm-inline`

That being said, I have found leaving the  `*`  also works. Ex: `.visible-sm-*` will hide things on small devices.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use more than one class block on your div, or it will get only the first classname. Try like this:

```
<div class="badge visible-xs visible-sm">text</div>
```

As seen in:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes